# How to migrate two Matomo installations into just one installation?

Tags: migration, matomo, piwiktracker

Matomo offers the possibility to manage multiple websites in just one installation and I would like to merge two separate Matomo installations into just one Matomo installation. How can I handle this? - Is there a best practice way?

Now: Two existing Matomo Installations:

```
 www.domain1.com/statistics
 www.domain2.com/statistics
```

Plan: just one Matomo Installation:

```
 statistics.domain3.com
```

How can export / import the data from the two existing installations and import it into just one installation? - Is there a export / import functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Plugin for Matomo that allows to to move single sites to another existing Matomo instance:
https://plugins.matomo.org/Migration

Comment: not able to execute a command on the console. Is there a different way? - Export and import table-by-table manually? - Does it work?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to export the database and import it in a Matomo instance where you can execute console commands.